# Coloring the rows depending on a particular column's value

Tags: php, colors, row

I am trying to color each row separately depending on the value of *fact* for each one of them. Instead, all I manage to do is to turn the whole table grey. I guess that the last value if *fact* is 'N' and so the last *if* is in effect. How do I cope with this?
Below is my code.

```
<?php
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
if($row['fact']='E')
    echo '<tr style="background-color:green">';
if($row['fact']='R')
    echo '<tr style="background-color:red">';
if($row['fact']='N')
    echo '<tr style="background-color:grey">';
echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['nume_port'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['adr'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['fact'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['owner'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['nivel'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['chei'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['rezon'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['dist'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['ult_inc'].'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}?>
```

Edit: this question is not a duplicate, since I've not suspected that the equals are the problem. I thought there's a problem with the method I used.

Comment: Wrong equals. One sets, two and three compare. Three compares more strictly, also checking variable type. So currently all conditions are met and since `gray` is your last case you get `gray`. You might want to use a `switch` there, then only one case could be met.

Comment: The switch is a good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `==` for comparison and not just `=` since that is an assignment operator.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: Thank you. I should have paid more attention.